# Краш с firebase

Tags: java, android

Вкрутил в свое приложение чат на firebase (взял отсюда - https://habrahabr.ru/company/google/blog/305308/ ).
Итак, суть в том, что я с MainActivity перехожу в ChatActivity посредством кнопки, обратно аппаратной кнопкой назад. Перехожу в первый раз - все ок, второй - ок. Третий - краш, лог ниже, уже всю голову переломал и немогу понять из-за чего это, помогите пожалуйста!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler

Process: ИМЯПАКЕТА, PID: 5113
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class com.google.firebase.iid.zzg
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.zzUl(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.config.internal.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.config.internal.zza$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.config.internal.zza$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznt$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zznp$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzc.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzc.zzsu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzc.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzj.zztp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zztr(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

в build добавлены такие dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
compile 'com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:2.9.2@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz.iconics:library:0.9.1@aar'
compile 'com.afollestad:assent:0.2.5'
compile 'com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:0.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

в build.gradle уровня проекта:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Возможно вы не отписались от слушателей данных firebase и крах происходит после смерти активити с активными слушателями.

Comment: Это как происходит?

Comment: Попробуйте проапдейдить либы как тут написано: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40219312/3212712

Comment: Не пропускает, говорит даунгрейднуть до 9.0.0